# How do I create a new file when there is already a similarly named one in the directory?

Tags: ivy

I want to create a file in Emacs called article.html.pm but I already have a file called article.html.pmd in the directory. Since I have Ivy it automatically finds the article.html.pmd and helpfully opens it since it's "close enough". But in this case, I do actually want to create a new file. Is there a good way to force emacs to create the file instead of fuzzy opening the old one? This is similar to [cant' create file with the same name in different directory in dired](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21074/cant-create-file-with-the-same-name-in-different-directory-in-dired) but I'm not using ido-mode so this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: See: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34244/create-a-directory-when-a-file-has-a-similar-name